# Delphi HTTPClient root page

Tags: json, http, delphi

I use THTTPClient instead of Indy to get a Json value from my API. I do it like this :

```
Url := 'http://example.com/api/index.php?get&latitude=' +
     TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(MapView.Location.Latitude.ToString)
     + '&longitude=' + TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(MapView.Location.Longitude.ToString);

Json := TToolHTTP.Get(Url);
```

The method to get is write below :

```
class function TToolHTTP.Get(aUrl: string): string;
var
  Client  : THTTPClient;
  Response: IHTTPResponse;
begin
  Result := '';

  Client := THTTPClient.Create;

  try
    try
      Response := Client.Get(aUrl);
      Result   := Response.ContentAsString;
    except
      ShowMessage('Error');
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Client);
  end;
end;
```

The first time or two first time I get my Json value, the third time I call this method with same url I get the content of the root page (http://example.com/index.html), and then when I call it the 4 time I get my Json. It's look like really random, but for sure I always get a Status Code HTTP 200.

Why sometime I get the html of the root page ?

Comment: When you are given the root index page, was there a preceding HTTP redirect to cause that? To check that, try setting `Client.HandleRedirects` to false and see what happens.

Comment: I have the same random problem, I add a guard who check result code to 200 and if result if json but that's not the best solution, thanks again

Comment: then you should capture the raw HTTP request/response data to see if anything is different between the cases that work vs don’t work. And then contact the site owner to ask about the issue.